# C++ outputstream remove stored data

Tags: c++, for-loop, outputstream

At the moment I am storing some data into an output stream like so

```
std::ostringstream oss;
std::string fileData;

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    oss << i;
    fileData += oss.str();
}
```

now the output is this

```
1
1
2
1
2
3
1
2
3
4
```

How can I clear all the data inside my oss variable so this doesn't happen?

P.S. I know I could just declare a new outputstream every time but that seems quite extreme.

Comment: Declaring the `ostringstream` inside the loop isn't "extreme", it's proper style.

Comment: Your output has got to be wrong because you have an index that goes from 0 to 3 inclusive, and the output goes from 1 to 4...

Comment: I just typed this out as a example, it isn't my actual code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace it with an empty string object:

```
oss.str(std::string());
```

Comment: Awesome, worked perfectly